# Handling rightclick in a firefox addon, only for the document

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm writing a fairly simple firefox add-on in which I want to do some things when the user clicks with the right mouse button anywhere on the webpage. I got it working, but strangely I also get all rightclicks from the firefox UI as well (like on the toolbar, tabs, urlbar etc).
I'm not interested in those of course.

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    // do stuff here
}, true);
```

I initially had this listener on window, but it doesn't change a thing.

Any hints on how I can trigger the event only when a rightclick happens in the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are running your code from a browser window overlay - so the `document` that you attach your event listener to is the XUL document of the browser window. If all you need are the events from the browser then you should attach your event listener to the browser. This still won't quite do what you want because the browser has some user interface as well (the notification bar) but it is easy enough to detect whether the event target is inside a content document:

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    if (e.target.ownerDocument.defaultView.top == window)
      return;

    // do stuff here
}, true);
```

This uses the fact that `window.top` is the top content window for windows inside the browser - they cannot cross the boundary to XUL code. For browser UI elements you will get the real top window however which is the window you run in.